# Gap for frameless full overlay hinged doors?

Tags: cabinetry, hinges

I'm constructing a cabinet that has doors that are flush against the adjoining wall/cabinet.  (technically, another cabinet in an RV)

If I use the "full overlay" version of [these hinges](http://www.rockler.com/blumreg-110deg-soft-close-blumotion-clip-top-overlay-hinges-for-frameless-cabinets-hinges), how do I know how much of a gap to leave between the door and the adjoining cabinet?  The two cabinets are flush.  (See illustration below)

Similarly, if I have two cabinet doors as shown in the illustration below, how much of a gap do I need between them?

I'm doing a Sketchup of my design and I need to know how much space to leave so I cut the doors to the right size.  I tried checking the installation instructions for the hinges, but I couldn't find the necessary information.

[image]

---

Update:
Below is a diagram from the [installation instructions for the hinges](http://go.rockler.com/tech/RTD10315697AA.pdf).  I feel like I should be able to find the information I need here, but the key measurement I need doesn't seem to be included...  Or, maybe it is?

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I found two good pages with relevant discussion.  There seemed to be consensus around 3/32".

Comment: Links - http://www.woodweb.com/knowledge_base/Space_Between_Cabinet_Doors.html and https://forum.canadianwoodworking.com/showthread.php?24702-Cabinet-door-gap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With those types of hinge, you do not need any clearance between doors.

My kitchen cupboards use that type of hinge and mostly have a 1/4" gap.

[image]

In one place there is no gap at all. I just trapped a piece of paper there with the door closed, when I opened the door the paper fell out. The door opens and closes smoothly. The hinge movement pulls the hinged end of the door inwards away from adjacent cabinets or walls.

[image]

At the other end I can wedge in a wooden spatula, I can still easily open the door with no noticable resistance.

[image]

I'd allow a gap so a solid wood door can expand as humidity changes seasonally. Other than that, there's no need for any significant gap.

Comment: Awesome.  What about between the doors?  I suppose I could do the math to calculate how much of a gap I'll need, but as you mentioned, there's some interesting geometry going on with these hinges that might cause my calculations to be off.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover the questions in your comment.